# Questioner's Remorse

Tags: discussion, feature-request

One way to reduce the volume of low-quality questions would he to allow the OP to remove a question (perhaps only if it had gotten no responses). I have a question posted right now, collecting "close" votes, that I would like to delete. Maybe this one is another. :-) If there is a way for me to delete the question, it is not obvious enough for my brains.

Comment: Are you suggesting that making it safe to ask low quality questions will reduce the number of low quality questions?

Comment: Don't delete, improve.

Comment: I really do not understand the slap-downs. Does disagreement with a suggestion warrant a down-vote? User192936 is deeply wounded. When I posted the question on StackOverflow that I would like to delete, it did not occur to me that it was off-topic. Otherwise it is a fine question. The only way to improve it (for StackOverflow) would be to change it into something completely different. I actually thought of doing that, but I could not think of a good question offhand. Everyone makes mistakes. To err is human, to forgive is not allowed. Edit: Just got slapped up again.

Comment: @user192936 -- Yes, [downvotes are different on meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) Also, see kiamlaluno's answer as to why people may "disagree".

Comment: If you need it to be migrated, you can either wait for the close votes to kick in or flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users are already allowed to deleted their own questions without an answer with a score higher than 0 (which includes also a question without any answer). In such case, the OP is allowed to delete her/his own question, even without closing it first.

Keep in mind that deleted questions are considered a bad sign, and you could be blocked from asking any further question, if you have too many deleted questions.  (Note that this is just one of several factors taken into consideration.)

Deleted questions are not a sign of less low-quality questions; it is rather the opposite. If some of your questions are deleted, it means they were low-quality questions, or they would not have been deleted. If they are not low-quality questions, they are surely questions not appropriate for the site where you asked them, which means they could be too localised, not real questions, or not constructive.

Comment: I missed the little "delete" clicker. Was looking for it in the editor. Gosh you guys are harsh.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @JiveDadson! That's not sarcasm; I, for one, am always happy to see a new face here. As Ernest said in his comment, downvotes here don't work in quite the same way they do on other sites. Please don't take it as us being harsh or trying to slap you down, because that's neither what it means nor what we intend. We always appreciate posts made in good faith, whether or not we agree with the specific suggestion.

Comment: @PopularDemand - Fear not. I had already put away the razor blades. Pardon me while I go shut off the engine of my car. It is idling in the closed garage.